# error: unknown type name 'pthread_mutex_t'

Tags: c, header, pthreads

Trying to compile a project and I am getting this error in thread.h.

```
inc/thread.h:38:15: error: unknown type name 'pthread_mutex_t'
```

When I look in thread.h, I see the following:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "rel_assert.h"
#define MUTEX pthread_mutex_t
```

It's the last line that is causing the error. 
After searching I found the pthread_mutex_t struct definition in pthreadtypes.h, so I tried to include that. Then I the following error:

`inc/pthreadtypes.h:16:3: error: #error "Never include <bits/pthreadtypes.h> directly; use <sys/types.h> instead."
inc/pthreadtypes.h:23:24: fatal error: bits/sched.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.`

If I include `<sys/types.h>` instead, I am back to my original error.
Any idea how to solve this.

UPDATE1
Tried to define it in the begining of my main like this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
//#include <libbladeRF.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{

pthread_mutex_t m;
return 0;
}
```

This actually works when I do a standalone c file and compile with gcc from the command line. But in the project I get errors. I must have done something wrong when I'm creating the project. Will try again.

Comment: As the error says you: also include `<sys/types.h>` (instead of `<bits/pthreadtypes.h>`)

Comment: So what files are you including?

Comment: Try putting `pthread_mutex_t MUTEX` without `#define`

Comment: You have a mismatch with arch you are compiling or with SDK.

Comment: I had a type that I fixed. I meant to `include <sys/types.h>.` Also removing the define doesn't seem to work. Still does not understand the `pthread_mutex_t` type is

Comment: Not sure what you mean. @LPs  I am running on Ubuntu 15.04, and I am using eclipse as IDE.

Comment: It should not be hard to present a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, and without one we can only guess at what's going on.  Moreover, the process of preparing one may even help you solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Try to post `rel_assert.h` contents

Comment: Does `#include <pthread.h> [put new-line here] pthread_mutex_t m; int main(void){}` compile?

Comment: moved comment to original post

Comment: All you'd need is `pthread.h`. Based on what you have said, it seems your build environment(PATH, compiler, libc, etc) is broken.

Answer (score 2):

After including 'pthread.h' and 'sys/types.h" header file, you should not see any issue. Might be you can cross verify the environment in which you are building this piece of code.

I hope you are using 'pthread' library(using "-lpthread" option) while compiling your code.

Comment: Where do I add this?
I tried like this:
`nios2-elf-gcc -xc -lpthread -MP -MMD -c `

Comment: I mean in the code it self you need to include those header files, but I see that you are already doing that. Please let me know, on which environment you are trying to compile. Might be you have to cross check your environment once.